# options_for_select with multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I'm trying to get is a dropdown with 2 fields (`name` and `account_code`) as a value

`<option value="1">ACC: John Doe</option>`

But current code

```
<%= select_tag :user_id, options_for_select(@users.map{|u| [u.name, u.account_code] }) %>
```

outputs the following:
`<option value="1">John Doe</option>`

How do I make it display both user's `account_code` and `name`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= select_tag :user_id, options_for_select(@users.map{|u| [u&.account_code+" "+u&.name, u.account_code] }) %>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: gives me an error #<NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass>

Comment: unfortunately I got the same error. Though it worked perfectly like this @users.map{|u| ["#{u.account_code}:  #{u.name}", u.account_code] }
Thanks for pointing the direction!

Answer (score 0):

Worked like this:

`@users.map{|u| ["#{u.account_code}:  #{u.name}", u.account_code] }`